# Get data from database between specified date and time range using linq-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table with two separate columns for date and time (SQL Server 2008).

I am trying to get the data between 1 minute before current time and 1 minute after current current time in my asp.net MVC (C#) application.

I have tried to use the where condition as:

```
ce.Start_Date.Add(ce.Start_Time) >= _currDateTime.AddMinutes(-1) && 
ce.Start_Date.Add(ce.Start_Time) <= _currDateTime.AddMinutes(1)
```

But from the above where condition, it throws an error:

```
The datepart millisecond is not supported by 
  date function dateadd for data type date.
```

How can I correct/rectify this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted to .AsEnumerable() and manipulate the date and time and return as .AsQueryable();

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the minutes in the `where` clause, try something like this instead:

```
for ce in data
let start = _currDateTime.AddMinutes(-1)
let end = _currDateTime.AddMinutes(1)
where ce.Start_Date.Add(ce.Start_Time) >= start && 
ce.Start_Date.Add(ce.Start_Time) <= end
select ce
```

LINQ to SQL is attempting to translate your `where` clause into valid T-SQL (using [T-SQL's `dateadd` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)) and it is having trouble doing so.

Comment: I have tried the above condition too and its not allowing to add ce.Start_Date.Add(ce.Start_Time) in where condition or even using let

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with server DATE type which does not have proper SQL translation. 
Try to make LINQ convert Date to DateTime, something like this:

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(ce.Start_Date).Add(ce.Start_Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to add "update time" field in table and compare current time with this field.